# How do I disable a UISwitch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, switch-statement, uiswitch

Is this possible to disable a UISwitch?  I do not mean putting it in an OFF state, I mean disabling user interaction, and having it appear gray.

In my app I have two conditions

```
if (condition == true) {  
  // UISwitch should be enabled  
} else {  
  // UISwitch should be visible, but disabled  
  // e.g uiswitch.enable=NO;  
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This should do it:

```objectivec
switch.enabled = NO;
```

or equivalently:

```objectivec
[switch setEnabled:NO];
```

where `switch` is whatever your `UISwitch` variable name is.

**Edit 18-Apr-2018**

The answer above is (clearly) an Objective-C solution, written well before anyone had ever heard of Swift. The Swift equivalent solution is, of course:

```swift
switch.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can. `UISwitch` inherits from `UIControl`, and `UIControl` has an `enabled` property. [Apple's UIControl Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl) has all of the details.

To **enable**

```
switch.enabled = YES;
```

To disable

```
switch.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 5):

For those looking for Swift 3,

```
switch.isEnabled = false // Disabled switch
```

I know you didn't ask for "off" state, but just in case anybody, like myself, stumbled upon here :

```
switch.isOn = false
```

Answer (score -6):

`[switchName enabled] = NO;`

Use that to disable your switch.

EDIT thanks to rckoenes: "You should not try to set a property via getter. You should use either the setter of . syntax property."

Comment: You should not try to set a property via getter. You should use either the setter of . syntax property.